# How to hide buttons in extjs calendar?

Tags: extjs, calendar

Is it possible to hide calendar buttons that are given in the figure in extjs modern toolkit running on mobile device?

[image]

I tried with `createButton: null`, but that didn't work.

In addition, while I can prevent creating new event with `beforeeventadd`, I don't even know what could be related event for the left button to prevent switching the views.

Comment: Can you show me online demo of extjs calendar with the button?

Comment: Here it is: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/31o7&view/editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look the following sample code fragment:

```
Ext.create('Ext.calendar.panel.Panel', {
    ...
    ...
    // For NOT compact Model
    createButton: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        switcher: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        nextButton: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        previousButton: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        todayButton: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        menuButton: {
            hidden: true,
        },
        compactOptions: {
            // For compact Model
            createButton: {
                hidden: true
            },
            switcher: {
                hidden: true,
            },
            nextButton: {
                hidden: true,
            },
            previousButton: {
                hidden: true,
            },
            todayButton: {
                hidden: true,
            },
            menuButton: {
                hidden: true,
            },
        },
        ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about the left button? How can I disable it or maybe get some beforetap event?

Comment: Do you need only MonthView?

Comment: Ok, now there will be no buttons ;)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need only week view. And I also need todayButton. But, I changed in your configuration hidden: false for todayButton in both models, but todayButton is not shown.

Comment: don‘t chane, just remove todayButton property.

Comment: It was originally removed, but todayButton is not shown by default (in mobile device mode).

Comment: Hm, maybe a bug/feature of compact mode.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you find a solution, please write a comment.